# Error installing mod_wsgi in centos with python2.7

Tags: centos, python, mod-wsgi

When i do "make" in mod_wsgi folder i get this error

I configured using following

```
./configure --with-apxs=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs   --with-python=/opt/python27/bin/python
```

> /usr/bin/ld:
>   /opt/python27/lib/libpython2.7.a(node.o):
>   relocation R_X86_64_32 against `a
>   local symbol' can not be used when
>   making a shared object; recompile with
>   -fPIC /opt/python27/lib/libpython2.7.a:
>   could not read symbols: Bad value
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   apxs:Error: Command failed with
>   rc=65536

[This link](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues) has the solution but i could not understand it fully

```
1)How can i found that i have compiled x32bit or x64 bit version of python 
2)I didn't understand about what symbolic link he was talking about
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The important bit is to rebuild Python with --enable-shared. The symlink comments are not relevant if you haven't done that and should't even apply with recent Python/mod_WSGI versions.

Comment: I tried that , i reinstalled with --enabled shared and same thing happens . how can i check that if enabled shared actually installed or not. i did this `./configure --prefix=/opt/python27 --enable-shared` is there any way to confirm that

Comment: You should see a libpython2.7.so in the /opt/python2.7/lib or /opt/python2.7/lib/python2.7/config directory.

Comment: I could not found that file i can see this file in both locations  `libpython2.7.a` . If file is not there does it means that i have to recompile python again. i remembered i used --enabled shared option

Comment: It means that what was installed didn't have shared library support enabled when it was built. Ensure that when you rebuild that you run 'make distclean' first before running 'configure' again and include '--enable-shared' in the options to 'configure'. You might even rename '/opt/python2.7' to '/opt/python2.7.static' while you do it to ensure that it recreates it and that installed version not causing problems.

Comment: thanks graham , mod_wsgi is installed now. i din't knew i had to use `make distclean`  thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Re-compile Python

Re-compiling Python with `--enable-shared` alone is not enough, because you'll get [error while loading shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7880454/2293304).

Supposed that you will install Python 2.7.x in `/usr/local/bin`, you should configure it with `LDFLAGS` option:

```
cd Python-2.7.x
make distclean  # For re-compiling only
./configure --enable-shared --prefix=/usr/local LDFLAGS="-Wl,--rpath=/usr/local/lib"
make
sudo make altinstall
```

(Use `altinstall` instead of `install` to avoid changing symbolic links of system Python and man pages. In short, `install` = `altinstall` + `bininstall` + `maninstall`)

### Compile `mod_wsgi`

Supposed that (a compiled version of) Apache is installed in `/usr/local/apache`, compile `mod_wsgi` against Python 2.7 like this:

```
cd mod_wsgi-x.x.x
./configure LDFLAGS="-Wl,--rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib" --with-apxs=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs --with-python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
make
sudo make install
```

If you compile `mod_wsgi` without `LDFLAGS`, Apache will complain:

```
Cannot load /usr/local/apache/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```